# merge menustrip mdi child into mdi parent form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms (form1, form2). form1 is mdiparent of form2.

When I add menustrip to form2, this menu is added to form1 and not seen in form2, how do I solve this?

Also can I separate menustrip of mdichild and mdiparent forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set either MenuStrip's `AllowMerge` property to 'false'

[MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.allowmerge(v=vs.110).aspx)